# Should I transpile my TypeScript application?

Tags: node.js, typescript, production-environment, ts-node

I recently started building a small project with TypeScript. It is a small application that runs some workflows based on received Webhook calls. This means that it exposes an Express app to handle these requests.

Currently I have an `npm` script that builds this project and transpiles it into JavaScript which can be then interpreted by Node.js. (The script runs: `tsc --build --clean`)

My question is, since this is not meant to be a library/package that will be published on NPM, is there any reason to transpile the project at all since I can just run it with `ts-node`?

I've been looking around for some information regarding this but couldn't find anything.

Are there any security, performance or any other implications when running the project directly with `ts-node` in a *production environment* instead of building it and running it with `node`?

Comment: In future, you can also consider [Deno](https://deno.land/), a runtime that runs TypeScript natively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your project. Most people transpile because it improves performance, consumes less system resources and provides more stability.

But in a small project this won't make much difference, so using ts-node may be sufficient.

Comment: I see, since I'm planning to build a Docker image for this service as well, so I decided to build it nonetheless. But it's good knowing that it doesn't matter much for future projects. Thanks!